# CDI: Intercepted method nested call from non-intercepted method of the same bean - should be invoked?

Tags: java, nested, cdi, interceptor, jboss-weld

If I have methods

```
public List<IrcEvent> getEventsByCriteria(IrcEventCriteria crit, boolean descending) {
    return getEventsByCriteria(crit, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, descending);
}

@JpaTransactional
public List<IrcEvent> getEventsByCriteria(IrcEventCriteria crit, int first, int count, boolean descending) {
     ...
}
```

then the first method must be also annotated @JpaTransactional right?

I just found out that when a bean calls its own intercepted method, then the interceptor is not triggered.
I assume that's because it's not the proxy called, but the "real instance" itself, thus it does not go through the proxy.

Is this covered by the spec / docs? I didn't find it yet.
I ask because I want to be sure that if I annotate all public methods, they will not start calling interceptors multiple times in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I can't recall seeing it in the spec, but that's the way proxies work. But anyway this is related to transaction propagation - whether invoking a transactional method with an existing running transaction should start a new transaction or not.

Get [Seam 3 persistence](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/PersistenceModule) module (with transaction support)

Comment: `but that's the way proxies work` - indeed. It's the same in EJB. If a bean calls its own methods, they do not go through the proxy. So if a method with transaction attribute `not-supported` calls its own method with transaction attribute `required`, no TX will be started which can be somewhat confusing.

Comment: Ad Seam 3 - this Java SE app, so I implemented simple transaction propagation myself.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd "internal" call is not via a contextual reference anymore, so it's not intercepted.